# Rails 4 : Able to modify non-accessible attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails. I used the Rails 4 method of *strong parameters* to specify which attributes are accessible in my User model.
Here is my `users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    User.create(user_params)
  end

  private   

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

Yet, I am able to update a user's non-accessible attributes by using `user.update_attributes(:id => 5, :name => "Bar")`, which should not be allowed. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** I started console by `rails console --sandbox`. Then added some users to the database using `.save` method and then called the `update_attributes` method.

Comment: Show your update action

Comment: Are you doing the `update_attributes` call in your controller or in the console? I ask because I don't see the call to update here in your controller and strong params will only work in the controller.

Comment: @Santosh: I just used the `update_attributes` command.

Comment: @Aaron: I did it in the console. So, is it always necessary to define `update`?

Comment: Did the attribute get updated in the DB? According to documentation even though function returns true, it does not update the values http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

Comment: @archie: Yes, I checked - it did get updated in the DB.

Comment: Strong parameters are only applicable in the controller and will not have any effect outside of one, when not using a `params` object, or on the console. As @spickermann explains, `strong_parameters` does a similar thing but a different way than the previous `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strong_parameters` protect you from mass assignment in this specific controller. It does not protect your from using the mass assignment elsewhere in the application or in the console.

So it does not protect the model like `attr_accessible` did. But this is how it should work. It is not the model's job to protect itself. It is the controller's job to protect the model. And there might be an `Admin::UsersController` that allows more than this `UsersController`.

Answer (score 1):

Only if [`attr_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) is set can you prevent mass-assignment via `update_attributes`, you should not be doing mass-assignment(using [`update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes)) in your application for fields that should not be altered, as it would also skip validations

N.B: `attr_accessible` is now deprecated so I doubt you can use it in rails 4 (If you still want to use the `attr_accessible` you need to add [`protected_attributes`](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) to your Gemfile)

Comment: Isn't that the whole point? Since `attr_accessible` is deprecated in Rails 4, that is why I was using strong parameters.

Comment: see my edits, if you still want to use `attr_accessible` you should add `protected_attributes` gem to your `Gemfile`

Comment: Yes I knew that, but I was kind of trying to learn the recommended way.

Comment: @Koderok the recommended way is to not allow wrong data to get to the Model, so you should not call `update_attributes` with invalid data